# Non-existence of solution for $x'=g(x)$ if $x(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $$g(x) = \cases{
       1 & $x < 0$ \\
       2 & $x\geq0$}$$

and the differential equation $x'=g(x).$ Prove that there is no solution if we set $x(0)=0$.

My idea is that the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=g(x)$ can be solved by $\displaystyle{\int\frac{1}{g(x)}dx}=t$. Now suppose $x(0)=0$; we set $t=0$ in the former equation and looks like it must be $\displaystyle{\int\frac{1}{g(x)}dx}=0$, but this can't be because $g(x)>0$ which implies $\displaystyle{\int\frac{1}{g(x)}dx}>0$.

Is this a correct argument?

Comment: Is $g(0)$ equal to $1$ or $2$...? Anyway you probably want a differentiable solution to write $x'$, do you see how that could be a problem?

Comment: Hi. Is $g(0)=2$, I just fixed it.

Comment: Then there is a solution: x(t)=2t for every nonnegative t.

Comment: What would be wrong with the solution $x(t)=t.g(t)$, except that it is not differentiable at $t=0$ ?

Comment: You need to swap one of the inequality signs in the definition of $g$. I cleaned up the source code, but i cannot tell offhand which is supposed to be which way.

Comment: @YvesDaoust This is one of the reasons I asked this question. The problem was copied as it was stated, and the first thing I thought was that I could define $x(t)=t$ if $t<0$ and $x(t)=2t$ if $t\geq0$. Assuming the question was right in what it asked to prove, I thought I may be wrong so I tried what I did above.
Maybe the fact that $x$ is not diff. at $t=0$ is enough to say that there is no general solution if $x(0)=0$?.

Comment: Yep, $x'(0)=2$ is incompatible with $x(t)=t$; the derivative is not just discontinuous, it is non-existent at $0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks. One last question: My approach is not good because of the $C$ right?. Couldn't I "save" it arguing that it must be $C=0$?. Since the left hand side has only factors in terms of $x$ without independent variables, it is gonna be $x(0)=0$ can't be $C\neq 0$.
Still, I believe there would be problems if some factor of the kind $x^{-k}$ with positive $k$ appears... :(

Comment: No. Specify the integration bounds and you'll stumble on a problem in your argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is not correct as the solution is 
$$\int\frac{dx}{g(x)}=t+C.$$
Anyway, $x'(t)$ is positive so that $x(t)$ is strictly increasing. Given $x(0)=0$, we have $x(-h)<0$ and $x(h)>0$, so that by the equation $x'(-h)=1$ and $x'(h)=2$, then integrating, $x(-h)=-h$ and $x(h)=2h$.

Taking the limit $h\to0$, $x'(t)$ is not defined at $t=0$, though we expected it to be $2$, a contradiction.

Actually, whatever the initial condition there is always a $t$ such that $x(t)=0$ and a solution never exists.

Comment: You're right, I messed it up.
But is what I was asked to prove possible?. If it is, then the problem to find such solution is that is not possible to find an $x$ differentiable for every $t$?.

Answer (score 1):

The non-differentiability of $g$ doesn't enter in to it, all Cure's argument depends on is that $g$ is positive everywhere. The error comes from

$\displaystyle{\int\frac{1}{g(x)}dx}=t$

which is only true up to a (usually implicitly assumed) arbitrary constant. By letting that slide and simply substituting in $t=0$, you've invalidated the actual solution.